# PHP таймаут в цикле?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, сразу прошу сильно не пинать, в PHP новичок, больше привык программировать на Делфях...

Собственно суть вопроса и сама проблема:
Есть скрипт который в определенное время получает большой массив строк (300-500)... 
в каждой строке по 2-4 слова (маленькое предложение, или словосочетание), задача перевести весь этот текст на Украинский, использую АПИ яндекса (http://code.google.com/p/translate-api/source/browse/trunk/)

```
<?
    include_once 'Yandex_Translate.php';  
    include_once 'Big_Text_Translate.php'; 
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=win-1251');

    function GTR($str,$in1,$in2) {  
    $translator = new Yandex_Translate();  
    $bigText = $str;  
    $textArray = Big_Text_Translate::toBigPieces($bigText);  
    $numberOfTextItems = count($textArray);  
    foreach ($textArray as $key=>$textItem){  
        $translatedItem = $translator->yandexTranslate($in1, $in2, $textItem);  
        $translatedArray[$key] = $translatedItem;  
    }  
    $translatedBigText = Big_Text_Translate::fromBigPieces($translatedArray);  
    return $translatedBigText;  
    }

for ($l = 0; $l <= count($array); $l++) 
{ 
$text=iconv('windows-1251','utf-8//IGNORE',$array[$l]);
$text=iconv('utf-8','windows-1251//IGNORE',GTR($text,'ru','uk'));
echo text;
}

?>
```

но в итоге выводится ошибка 
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in\Yandex_Translate.php on line 43

вопрос в следующем, как например или разбить этот масив на маленькие и по очереди перевести, или сделать какой то таймаут перед каждой отправкой запроса на перевод, чтобы нормально его перевести...

буду рад любым советам!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант решения, это установить значение execution time limit больше 30 секунд!

Либо через функцию: `set_time_limit(0);` (0 - бесконечно), либо в php.ini значение параметра изменить.

Comment: в php.ini изменить не получится, так как скрипт будет использоватся разными людьми на разных серверах и хостингах...

пробовал сразу формировать из масива нужный мне результат (формат вывода (не массив а большая строка)) но при отправке на перевод 
выдает ошибку Request uri too largeRequest uri too large) . 
хотя сам класс перевода должен легко переводить и большые тексты как описано и показано в документации к АПИ...

Comment: Request uri too large === слишком длинная строка GET параметров